# How to solve the recurrence relation T(n)=T(n/3)+T(n/6)+1

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I've been trying to solve the next recurrence relation T(n)=T(n/3)+T(n/6)+1

I don't know where to start. I thought about drawing a recursion tree first and then solve it, but I don't know if it's right.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Akra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method), which is a generalization of the Master Theorem for solving divide-and-conquer recurrences with sub-problems of different sizes. It applies to recurrences of the form:

[image]

for positive constants a, constants b in (0,1), g(n) in O(n^c) and h(n) in O(n/log^2(n)).

In this case:

[image]

Following the method, we need the p value such that:

[image]

Solving this equation for p gives p=0.48954...

The Akra-Bazzi theorem says that the complexity for the algorithm is then:

[image]

which when solved given g(u) = 1 yields:

[image]

Comment: Splitting the parts up and solving them individually is not  a valid method, and produces the wrong result here. An example of why the method is flawed: you can't solve T(n) = 2T(n/2) by writing T(n) = T(n/2) +T(n/2) and then solving the parts. T(n) = 2T(n/2) has solution T(n)=Theta(n), and T(n) = T(n/2) has solution T(n)=Theta(1).

Comment: @PaulHankin Yeah, you're right, my mistake

Comment: The new answer is great!